# Постраничное разбиение на Java

Tags: java

Привет ХешКод.Возник интересный вопрос,помогите сделать такую программку,если не сложно,конечно.Пишешь 1 она выводит первые десять файлов,пишешь 2 она выводит следующую десятку и так пока файлы не кончатся в директории(они берутся из папки ,обычные txt файлы).
Вообщем вот так).Вот вам код в помощь,хотя не знаю может ли он помочь:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class page {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;

        File file = new File("C:\\prov");
        String list[] = file.list();

        int len = new File("C:\\prov\\").list().length;

        ArrayList<String> pages = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
            for (int itt = 0; itt < list.length; itt++) {
                File fileread = new File("C:\\prov\\" + list[itt]);
                BufferedReader brl = null;
                try {
                    brl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(fileread), "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // pages.add("page-" + i);
                try {
                    while ((s = brl.readLine()) != null) {
                        pages.add(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        paginate(pages, 10);

    }// main end

    static <T> void paginate(List<T> pages, int pagesPerOut) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i += pagesPerOut) {
            System.out.println(paginate(pages, i, pagesPerOut));
            System.out.println("==============================");
        }
    }

    static <T> List<T> paginate(List<T> pages, int start, int count) {
        int end = start + count > pages.size() ? pages.size() : start + count;
        return pages.subList(start, end);
    }

}
```

Я,конечно,понимаю,что писать код так не будут,но может найдутся добрые люди,готовые помочь.

Comment: Гениальный вопрос...

Comment: Ага))Мне вот интересно как это на Java сделать?

Comment: @Barmaley не поможете?

Comment: А что у вас тут не получается?

Comment: не знал как сделать,чтобы при вводе(это не проблема) выводились десять первых файлов,содержимое их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот набросал, может быть поможет. Без обработки исключений, очень сырой вариант. Страницы начиная с нуля.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetFileList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TxtFiles file = new TxtFiles("D:\\");  //Путь к папке
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pageNum = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the page(Beginning from 0, -1 for exit):");
            pageNum = sc.nextInt();
            file.printPage(pageNum);
        } while (pageNum != -1);

        System.out.println("GoodBY!");
    }
}

class TxtFiles {

    private File file;
    private String pathToTxtFiles;
    private File[] files;
    private List<String> txtFiles;

    public TxtFiles(String path) {

        pathToTxtFiles = path;
        file = new File(path);
        files = file.listFiles();
        txtFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        importOnlyTxtFiles();

    }

    private void importOnlyTxtFiles() {
        for (File fl : files) {
            if (fl.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                txtFiles.add(fl.toString());
        }
    }

    public void printPage(int numOfPage) {
        if (numOfPage == -1)
            return;
        if (numOfPage < 0 || numOfPage > txtFiles.size() / 10) {
            System.out.println("Wrong page!");
            return;
        }

        int limit = (numOfPage < txtFiles.size() / 10) ? numOfPage * 10 + 10
                : txtFiles.size();

        for (int i = numOfPage * 10; i < limit; i++) {
            System.out.println(txtFiles.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,большое,а не могли бы вы подсказать примерный алгоритм реализации этого в сервлете,т.е ,чтобы номера страниц были ссылками

Comment: Если у Вас есть время разбираться, то может вам [сюда][1] ?


  [1]: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf